# Dynamically drill down nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I dynamically drill down my array of objects? Let me explain. Say I have this array of objects with subarrays:

```
var arrOfObjects = [

    { 
        name: 'something',
        subArray: [ {
            name: 'nested something'   
        } ]
    },
    { 
        name: 'something else',
        subArray: [ {
            name: 'nested something else'   
        } ]
    }];
```

and a reference to know which array in the hierarchy I need to modify

```
var referenceArr = [1,0];
```

How do I use this reference to generate the proper location in my data array, in this case, I would want to get to

```
    arrOfObject[1]['subArray][0]['name'];
// 'subArray' and 'name' are always the same
```

The reference array could be any length, so

```
var referenceArr= [0];
```

indicates modifying:

```
arrOfObject[0]['name'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this function:

```
function getValue(source, path){
    var result = source;
    while(path.length){
        result = result[path.shift()];
        if(path.length && !result.subArray)
            throw new Error('Incorrect path!');
        else if(path.length)
            result = result.subArray;
        else
            result = result.name;
    }
    return result;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3L2tvo1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/18gptden/)

```
var arrOfObjects = [

    { 
        name: 'something',
        subArray: [ {
            name: 'nested something'   
        } ]
    },
    { 
        name: 'something else',
        subArray: [ {
            name: 'nested something else'   
        } ]
    }];

for(var i=0; i<arrOfObjects.length;i++){
   alert(arrOfObjects[i].subArray[0].name)
}
```